# Программирование в среде Unix

Tags: c, книги

Посоветуйте,пожалуйста,какую-нибудь хорошую книгу для изучения программировании на C в среде Unix(на русском языке)

Comment: @mango44 Вам требуется информация по C или по Unix?

Comment: Программирование на языке С в среде Unix

Comment: Закрывальщики, хотя бы комментарии со ссылками на уже готовые ответы оставляйте!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Классические книги по C**

- [Керниган, Ритчи. Язык программирования Си.](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-0891-9.html) Отличный учебник по языку и хорошей практике программирования (C89).
- Харбисон, Стил. Язык программирования C. (С99)

**Классические книги по Unix**

- [Стивенсон, Раго. UNIX. Профессиональное программирование](http://www.symbol.ru/alphabet/503720.html)
- [Керниган, Пайк. UNIX. Программное окружение](http://www.symbol.ru/alphabet/82361.html)

Comment: @mango44 тоже хорошая книжка --   [Роберт Лав. Linux: системное программирование](http://www.chitai-gorod.ru/catalog/book/358548/)  или [pdf](http://scanlibs.com/linux-sistemnoe-programmirovanie-2-e-izdanie/)